# AWS CLI environment create error CREATE_FAILED, reason: resources failed to create

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I used to deploy a Java web application to Elastic Beanstalk (EC2) as root user without this problem. Now I'm using a recommended way of deploying as IAM service user and I get the following errors. I suspect it's because of lack of permissions (policies) but I don't know what policies should I assign to the IAM user.

QUESTION: Could you help me in finding the right policies?

commands:

```
eb init --profile eb_admin
eb create --single
```

output of the 2nd command:

```
Printing Status:
2019-05-26 12:08:58    INFO    createEnvironment is starting.
2019-05-26 12:08:59    INFO    Using elasticbeanstalk-eu-central-1-726173845157 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
2019-05-26 12:09:26    INFO    Created security group named: awseb-e-ire9qdzahd-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-L5VUAQLDAA9F
2019-05-26 12:09:42    ERROR   Stack named 'awseb-e-ire9qdzahd-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED'  Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [MountTargetSecurityGroup, AWSEBEIP, sslSecurityGroupIngress, FileSystem]. 
2019-05-26 12:09:42    ERROR   Creating security group failed Reason: The vpc ID 'vpc-7166611a' does not exist (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidVpcID.NotFound; Request ID: c1d0ce4d-830d-4b0c-9f84-85d8da4f7243)
2019-05-26 12:09:42    ERROR   Creating EIP: 54.93.84.166 failed. Reason: Resource creation cancelled
2019-05-26 12:09:42    ERROR   Creating security group ingress named: sslSecurityGroupIngress failed Reason: Resource creation cancelled
2019-05-26 12:09:44    INFO    Launched environment: stack-overflow-dev. However, there were issues during launch. See event log for details.
```

Important!

I use a few `.ebextensions` scripts in order to initialize the environment:

- nginx
- https-instance-securitygroup
- storage-efs-createfilesystem
- storage-efs-mountfilesystem

After reviewing the logs, I also noticed that I forgot to create VPC which is required for EFS filesystem. Could it be that 1 failed script (`storage-efs-createfilesystem`) is the root cause of subsequent failing operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the lack of VPC has caused the other resources to fail to create. Elastic Beanstalk and the storage-efs-createfilesystem extension use CloudFormation underneath.

storage-efs-createfilesystem Cfn template creates MountTargetSecurityGroup SG and that failed due to lack of VPC. The AWSEBEIP, sslSecurityGroupIngress and FileSystem resource creation is then cancelled.